# OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application. message after upgrading to Flutter 3.16

Tags: flutter

Immediately after upgrading to Flutter version 3.16.0, I am receiving these messages for the first time:

**OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.**

**Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.**

I read about "Android Predictive Back", but was unsuccessful implementing the migration steps detailed at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back -- I could not get PopScope working as expected (as WillPopScope was), even after adding 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.

There is very little documentation about this topic as regards Flutter specifically. Can someone please explain in detail what the above manifest definition affects in a Flutter application, and how to successfully replace a WillPopScope function with PopScope?

I was using WillPopScope to save changes the user made in a screen when the user tapped the system Back button, like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        if (widget.selectionMode == 1) {
          saveAndClose();
        }
        return Future.value(true); // Allow screen to close now
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        ...
```

This is the new code that is not working -- the system back button does not pop the screen at all now:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
          saveAndClose();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else interested, here is the solution of how to implement this correctly.

In this example, the purpose is to implement "Tap back again to close the app" for Android apps: The first time the user hits the Back button, a Snackbar is shown for 3 seconds and the second time, if within those 3 seconds, the app closes.

1. Declare these two variables for the screen:

```
bool _canPopNow = false;
DateTime? _currentBackPressTime;
```

2. Wrap the Scaffold body in PopScope() like this:

```
      body: PopScope(
        // Implements tap back again to close app
        canPop: _canPopNow,
        onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
          if (!didPop) {
            tapBackAgainToCloseApp();
          }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
```

3. Add this function that is called from PopScope():

```
  void tapBackAgainToCloseApp() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (_currentBackPressTime == null || now.difference(_currentBackPressTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 3)) {
      _currentBackPressTime = now;
      showSnackBar(context, "Tap back again to close the app"); // calling a custom SnackBar function
      setState(() {
        _canPopNow = true; // Temporarily let user exit app on the next back tap
      });
      Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 3),
        () {
          // Disable pop availability after 3-second timeout
          setState(() {
            _canPopNow = false;
            _currentBackPressTime = null;
          });
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**PopScope** has one more property **canPop**, use this property.